# Hacer un IsSelected en un ComboBox con el SelectedValue [UWP]

Tags: xaml, combobox, uwp, enum

Tengo un ComboBox, que ya tiene unos items asignados, cargados por medio de una enumeracion (Enum):

```
public enum TERCERO_TIPOID : byte {
        [Display(Name = "Nit")]NIT,
        [Display(Name = "Cedula Cuidadania")]CC,
        [Display(Name = "Cedula Extranjeria")]CE,
        [Display(Name = "Pasaporte")]PASAPORTE,
        [Display(Name = "Tarjeta Extranjeria")]TAR_EXT,
        [Display(Name = "Doc. Id Extranjeria")]DOCID_EXT,
        [Display(Name = "Tarjeta Identidad")]TAR_IDEN,
        [Display(Name = "Nuip")]NUIP,
        [Display(Name = "Codigo")]COD,
        [Display(Name = "Otros")]OTRO = 9 }
```

En el comboBox me muestra ya el DataAnotation del name, hasta ahi todo bien, pero en la base de datos cuando hago la consulta de la tabla Personas hay un campo llamado "TipoDoc" que por requisitos es un campo de bit, por ende al cargar TipoDoc me trae un numero de 1 a 9 no mas, pero nesecito que al cargar un usuario el comboBox me carge el tipo de documento que tiene.

Si lo hago, por ejemplo con un `Combo_Tipo.SelectedIndex = 3;` el comboBox sleccionara el tercero en la enumeracion "Pasaporte", pero yo nesecito que el ComboBox se seleccione con el value, que en vez de usar el SelectedIndex use el SelectedValue. Que al ponerle por ejemplo `Combo_Tipo.SelectedValue = "Nit";` me deje seleccionado el tipo de documento NIT.

Pero al hacerlo el no me deja hacerlo. ¿Como lo hago?¿que estoy haciendo mal?

El SelectedIndex me captura y me asigna el valor en le combo.

El SelectedValue solo me captura el dato  del Combo pero no me lo asigna cuando lo necesito.

Combo:

```
<ComboBox Header="Tipo Documento:" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" x:Name="Combo_TipoDoc" SelectedItem="{Binding Tipoid, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

y este es el Objeto en el campo en el VM:

```
public TERCERO_TIPOID Tipoid { get => tipoid; set { tipoid = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); } }
private TERCERO_TIPOID tipoid;
```

y asi lo cargo en el codeBehind de la ventana XAML osea `TerceroPage.xaml.cs`

```
this.Combo_TipoDoc.ItemsSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(TERCERO_TIPOID)).Cast<TERCERO_TIPOID>();
```

Comment: Puedes mostrar el codigo del itemSource de tu Combo?

Comment: Litsto actualice la pregunta puede revisar como lo cargo y le hago Binding

Comment: Acabo de hacer una pequeña prueba y el selectedItem le asigne un enum TERCERO_TIPOID.NIT y si lo mostro seleccionado, tal vez olvidaste asignarle el bindingContext a la vista?

Comment: Si, si se le hace asi es facil, lo que pasaba era que la base de datos trae, por ejemplo en el campo de TipoDoc = 4, la base de datos no almacenaba enumeraciones, o cadenas, la base de datos trae nuemeros, y esos numeros se tenian que relacionar con el index del enum

Comment: No entiendo bien tu duda, pero creo que lo que te falta es castear el int de la bd al Enum y viceversa?

Comment: si exacto eso es

Comment: Te recomiendo que edites tu pregunta si es como indicas lo que te falta es hacer un parse de int a enum y viceversa, con esto ayudas a los que tienen la misma duda y favorece a que tengas mas respuestas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como indicas en tu comentario lo que te falta es hacer un casteo de `int` a `Enum` y viceversa, aqui te dejo un ejemplo:

```
 public enum TERCERO_TIPOID : byte
    {
        [Display(Name = "Nit")]
        NIT,//0
        [Display(Name = "Cedula Cuidadania")]
        CC,//1
        [Display(Name = "Cedula Extranjeria")]
        CE,//2
        [Display(Name = "Pasaporte")]
        PASAPORTE,//3
        [Display(Name = "Tarjeta Extranjeria")]
        TAR_EXT,//4
        [Display(Name = "Doc. Id Extranjeria")]
        DOCID_EXT,//5
        [Display(Name = "Tarjeta Identidad")]
        TAR_IDEN,//6
        [Display(Name = "Nuip")]
        NUIP,//7
        [Display(Name = "Codigo")]
        COD,//8
        [Display(Name = "Otros")]
        OTRO = 9
    }
```

ya que el datasource que indicas en tu pregunta es una colección de los enums de `TERCERO_TIPOID`:

```
Combo_TipoDoc.ItemsSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(TERCERO_TIPOID)).Cast<TERCERO_TIPOID>();
```

Como lo quieres obtener es el valor `entero` o `byte` de tu enum puedes hacerlo de esta manera obteniendolo desde el `SelectedItem`:

```
var  document = (TERCERO_TIPOID)Combo_TipoDoc.SelectedItem;
int idDocumento = (int)document;
```

Y para convertir de `entero` a `Enum`:

```
var valorEntero=3;
TERCERO_TIPOID dipoDoc = (TERCERO_TIPOID)valorEntero;
```